# Drawing labels on main chart with bottom indicator

Tags: tradingview-api

I'm trying to solve two problems with an indicator script.

1. It's a bottom indicator, and I would like to draw labels on the main chart. How? I can't figure it out.
2. Secondly the way I have my conditions setup for drawing the label, it gets drawn on multiple candles. How do I restrict it to only draw on the first occurrence?

Here's example code that I use. I appreciate any help here.

```
study("Trend Up and Down", overlay=false)
l = label.new(bar_index, na)
//buy label
if plus > minus
    label.set_text(l, "B")
    label.set_color(l, color.green)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_labelup)

//sell label
if plus < minus
    label.set_text(l, "S")
    label.set_color(l, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_labeldown)
```

Maybe I forgot to add how `plus` and `minus` get calculated. For simplicity's sake, let's assume that's a simple moving average crossover. Would I have to use `crossover` with a boolean comparison or is the way I have it `plus > minus` the correct way of labeling the candles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example how to plot only the most recent signal on the chart.

```
//@version=4
study("Trend Up and Down", overlay=true)

var l = label.new(0,0)

_smaSlow=sma(close, 200)
_smaFast=ema(close, 50)

_longCond = crossover(_smaFast, _smaSlow)
_shortCond = crossunder(_smaFast, _smaSlow)

if(_longCond)
    label.set_x(l, bar_index)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.belowbar)
    label.set_style(l,  label.style_label_up)
    label.set_text(l, "Buy")
    label.set_color(l, color.green)

if(_shortCond)
    label.set_x(l, bar_index)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(l,  label.style_label_down)
    label.set_text(l, "Sell")
    label.set_color(l, color.red)

plot(_smaSlow, color=color.blue)
plot(_smaFast, color=color.orange)
```

[image]

It's more common to plot all buy and sell signals on a chart, here's an example how to do it.

```
//@version=4
study("Trend Up and Down", overlay=true)

_smaSlow=sma(close, 200)
_smaFast=ema(close, 50)

_longCond = crossover(_smaFast, _smaSlow)
_shortCond = crossunder(_smaFast, _smaSlow)

plotshape(_longCond, size=size.small, style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green, location=location.belowbar, text="Buy")
plotshape(_shortCond, size=size.small,  style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red, location=location.abovebar, text="Sell")

plot(_smaSlow, color=color.blue)
plot(_smaFast, color=color.orange)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That makes a whole lot of sense. I didn't know we can plot something depending on a boolean condition.

Comment: Urso, I found a flaw in my question. I didn't mean to say "the most recent", I meant on the first occurrence of a signal. The way I have it, the shape gets plotted multiple times, it would be better if it just plots on the first candle. I have multiple `and` clauses, which overlap, and that produces multiple shapes. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First question has been answered. It's not possible to draw labels on different panels. FYI